# Dynamic SQL statements performance in package vs procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic, oracle11g, package

our application currently uses a procedure that dynamically builds a large portion of the SQL statements to be executed. And this procedure is executed every weekend about 10,000 times.

The Issue: Recently our DBA noticed that the Soft Parse times for this procedure execution is a lot and he suggested that we use a Package that builds the sql statements once for each combination of inputs. This since there are only limited number of possible input combinations. But he was very unsure about what other parameters need to be set for this design and how caching of SQL works.

The current procedure crudely looks like:

```
Procedure P (v1 IN NUMBER, v2, IN NUMBER)
    v_table_name            VARCHAR2(30);

    v_table_name := 'X' || v1;
    v_sql = ' INSERT INTO ' || v_table_name || 'values..';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql USING aaa;

    v_table_name := 'Y' || v2;
    v_sql = ' SELECT abc FROM ' || v_table_name ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
    INTO bbb USING kkk;
END;
```

So based on the recommendations, the new package replacing this should look like:

```
PACKAGE BODY PK AS

v_sql_1 VARCHAR2 := '';
v_sql_2 VARCHAR2 := '';
v_sql_3 VARCHAR2 := '';.... many more

PROCEDURE P (v1 IN NUMBER, v2, IN NUMBER)
IF (*condition A*) THEN         <Conditions can occur many times>
   IF (v_sql_1 = '') THEN
      v_sql_1 := 'INSERT INTO ' || v_table_name ||...  <Construct once>        
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_1 USING aaa;
   ELSE
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql_1 USING aaa;
   END IF;
END IF;

IF (*condition B*) THEN
   IF (v_sql_2 = '') THEN
      v_sql_2 := 'SELECT abc FROM ' || v_table_name....  <Construct once>        
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO bbb USING kkk;
   ELSE
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO bbb USING kkk;
   END IF;
END IF;
```

Does this design improve Caching/Execution Plan? Does it need any further modifications/adjustments to improve on our Soft Parse times?

All feedback is appreciated.

Comment: Execution plans refer to specific *tables*, just like compiled programs refer to specific APIs and structures. You change the API, you have to recompile. Trying to "parameterize" the table itself is a bad design, no matter how you package it. The query optimizer can't guess what the query does, much less which table you are using or which plan to use, without fully parsing the query. In fact, it will have to do the exact same processing it does for raw SQL queries. Nothing is gained by packaging in terms of execution plan caching

Comment: Is there a method in which i can simulate prepared statements? Or drive the sql to use a existing plan in the Shared pool?  Is the construction of Table Name the primary concern here?.. If i can get that fixed how can i modify the code to reduce soft parse times?

Comment: Dynamic SQL *is* the root problem here. The execution plan issue is just one of the consequences. Exposure to SQL injection attacks is another. Another consequence is that the developer (you) has no idea what queries actually get executed so he can't optimize them.  The *sensible* solution is to fix it is to remove dynamic SQL generation. Another option is to instruct the optimizer to use specific execution plans for specific calls. This is a *very* advanced technique, used only when it's not possible to fix the real problem. You'd have to specify the plan for every combination though.